# How to setup a Django server state before starting gunicorn

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I'm building a **Django** server which I'm going to host using **gunicorn** and want to setup its (Django's) inner state (fetch and cache some data from the blockchain, start couple threads that would perform some background updates etc.) before starting an actual HTTP server with my API endpoints. While it's fairly easy to do with the "manage.py runserver" (create my own implementation with all the actions I need before actual server starting), I'm struggling to wrap my head around the best way to do that with the WSGI gunicorn server which seems to start right away with no obvious way to specify any pre-run actions.

The way I do it right now is as follows:

```py
import asyncio
from django.core.management.commands.runserver import BaseRunserverCommand
from channels.management.commands.runserver import Command as RunChannels
from QTCore.blockchain.blockchain_interop import BcInterop

class Command(RunChannels):
    def inner_run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        async def setup_bc():
            self.stdout.write('Spinning up blockchain interop modules...', ending='\n')
            await BcInterop.init()
            self.stdout.write('Blockchain interop is ready', ending='\n')

        main_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(main_loop)

        try:
            main_loop.run_until_complete(setup_bc())
            self.stdout.write('Launching Django server...', ending='\n')
            super(Command, self).inner_run(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            main_loop.close()
```

Comment: `all the actions I need before actual server starting`.  Can you expand on what this means, possibly with code samples.  What information do these scripts output.  How is that information then received by your django app?

Comment: In what way is starting gunicorn any different from starting the dev server?

Comment: @v25
Edited my question with the code sample. The Django server then proceeds to call the BcInterop whenever needed, as it holds the data and threads I'm using.

The problem here is that the BcInterop references some of the Django apps and their components, wich means that the server itself has to be fully initialized before I perform my custom tasks. Which is not the case when I try to run it in a wsgi.py (gunicorn entrypoint)